# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Identity with Web API project

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have ASP.Net Core 2.2 project that we are upgrading to Core 3. I got the problem with authentication that I was able to reproduce in the scaffolded Core 3 project. I noticed that if I scaffold MVC or Angular template with Individual User Account, I don't get the error. Probably because it is going to the same port - not sure.

And API template *doesn't* have the option of Store user accounts in-app. So I am using `ng new` plus scaffolded code in Angular template, and the back-end code generated by Web API template and it is running on a different port.

Now the problems trying to add authentication to Angular:

- when I click on Register, IdentityServer register page **does** come up with URL https://localhost:44342/Identity/Account/Register?returnUrl=https://localhost:4200/authentication/login (44342 is the port of the back end), but all of the css or javascript return 404. For example, `https://localhost:44342/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404`. So the page is obviously unusable
- when I click Login, the page **does not** come up; I am getting `GET https://localhost:44342/.well-known/openid-configuration net::ERR_FAILED`. Needless to say that accessing this URL from the browser works fine. I also get another error right after: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44342/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Not sure if this is false positive or legit... all other APIs work through CORS without any problems

I am not necessary asking for solution, but rather for some troubleshooting guidance. Most of the code that gets executed is IdentityServer code that I have trouble to control or debug. I haven't seen any docs that guide you through building independent front end and back end with new architecture where IdentityServer and OIDC is default implementation of the authentication.